# Type '{ array: {}[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {}[]'. Property 'array' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {}[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

This is my component for rendering tables with data.

```
const TablesToShow = (array: {}[]): JSX.Element[] => {
 
  const newArray : any = array.map((element: any, index: number ) : any => {

    // const [ accesory, setExercise] = useState()
  // add ability to change 

    const changeHandlerForFirstButton = (): void => {
   
  
    }
    const changeHandlerForSecondButton = (): string[]  => {
      console.log(element[1][1].MusclesInvolvedInExercise, element[1][1].typesOfMovement)  
      return MusclesInAccesory;
    }

    const changeHandlerForThirdButton = (): string[]  => {
      console.log(element[1][2].MusclesInvolvedInExercise, element[1][2].typesOfMovement)  
      return MusclesInAccesory
    };
    let firstExerciseLoad: number[] = element[0].load[0]
    let secondExerciseLoad: number[] = element[0].load[1]
    let thirdExerciseLoad: number[] = element[0].load[2]
    let firstExerciseLoadAccesory: number[] = element[1][0].load
    let secondExerciseLoadAccesory: number[] = element[1][1].load
    let thirdExerciseLoadAccesory: number[] = element[1][2].load
  
    return <div className="Basis">
      
       <h4>{index+1}. Training unit</h4>

        <table className='ContensOfTheTable'>
            <thead>
              <tr>  
                <th><h3>I. {element[0].mainExercise}</h3></th>
                <th>Intensity</th>
                <th>Sets</th>
                <th>Reps</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><h3>{Math.round(firstExerciseLoad[0])} kg</h3></td>
                <td><h3>{firstExerciseLoad[1]}</h3></td>
                <td><h3>{firstExerciseLoad[2]}</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><h3>{Math.round(secondExerciseLoad[0])} kg</h3></td>
                <td><h3>{secondExerciseLoad[1]}</h3></td>
                <td><h3>{secondExerciseLoad[2]}</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><h3>{Math.round(thirdExerciseLoad[0])} kg</h3></td>
                <td><h3>{thirdExerciseLoad[1]}</h3></td>
                <td><h3>{thirdExerciseLoad[2]}</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><h3>Accesory Exercises</h3></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>Sets</td>
                  <td>Reps</td>      
              </tr>                
              <tr className="Accesories">
                <td><h3>II. {element[1][0].accesory} </h3></td>   
                <td><button onClick={changeHandlerForFirstButton}>console.log</button></td>
                <td><h3> {firstExerciseLoadAccesory[0]}</h3></td>
                <td><h3> {firstExerciseLoadAccesory[1]}</h3></td>
              </tr>   
              <tr className="Accesories">
                <td><h3>III. {element[1][1].accesory} </h3></td>
                <td><button onClick={changeHandlerForSecondButton}>console.log</button></td>
                <td><h3> {secondExerciseLoadAccesory[0]}</h3></td>
                <td><h3> {secondExerciseLoadAccesory[1]}</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr className="Accesories">
                <td><h3>IV. {element[1][2].accesory} </h3> </td>
                <td><button onClick={changeHandlerForThirdButton}>console.log</button></td>
                <td><h3>{thirdExerciseLoadAccesory[0]}</h3></td>
                <td><h3>{thirdExerciseLoadAccesory[1]}</h3></td>
              </tr>
        
            </tbody>
         
        </table>
      </div>
      })
      return newArray
    }
```

this is the data from my App file :

```
function App() {

  // const [first, second] = useState()

  return (
    // let [accesory, setExercise] = useState(Projection.map(element[1][0].accesory))
    <div className='Flexi'>
      <TablesToShow  array={array}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get this error whenever I try to pass array as a prop :

```
 Type '{ array: {}[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {}[]'.
  Property 'array' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {}[]'.
```

I would like to know how can I pass an array of objects , so I can pass different {}[] for this component to render tables ?

Also when I try to put type of element as {} (which it is) I get error that `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '1' can't be used to index type '{}'`